# Question about external libraries and namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

In a class library I am building, I am including files from [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). My question: Should I wrap my namespace around the HtmlAgilityPack classes? For example:

```
namespace HtmlAgilityPack {
    internal... // blah blah blah

}
```

becomes:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    namespace HtmlAgilityPack {
        internal... // blah blah blah

    }
}
```

I am thinking of doing this to prevent conflicts in projects that already use HtmlAgilityPack. Is there any other reason to do this? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users should be able to uniquely identify class names using namespaces, that's the whole idea of namespaces in the first place imo. There are workarounds like aliases but I wouldn't introduce this problem for the users of your library. That being the case I would wrap the `HtmlAgility` namespace as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you need worry about this. For projects which already use HtmlAgilityPack, you can just simply share the  HtmlAgilityPack namespace with them. I don't see the conflict issue here.

Comment: Is it possible that the compiler will complain if my watered-down version of HtmlAgilityPack adds classes to the namespace that the full version of HAP (in the project) already has created? (i.e. clobbering)

Comment: I see, you want to physically include the files from HtmlAgilityPack?  In that case, yes, I think you need wrap it in your own namespace.

Comment: I was considering including the HAP dll file, but I would rather embed the dependency right in my library. Otherwise, the user would need to include two dll files just to use one library.

Comment: Not sure how the license work, but I think there is some limitation the you can "copy and paste" that way. Include two dll files won't be big issues, in .Net world, there is few library which don't have any dependency, I won't worry about unless you have a specific reason.

Comment: The license says that I can make derivative works, so I should be fine :). I am going to keep it as a single file, so that my users (which will probably be me and myself) don't have to worry about dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    namespace HtmlAgilityPack {
        internal... // blah blah blah

    }
}
```

do

```
namespace MyNamespace.HtmlAgilityPack 
{
        internal... // blah blah blah
}
```

this is a common way, yes doing this is good, and because of this namespaces are alive.